# How to use IF ELSE condition inside Rule of jquery.validate.js

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

How to use the IF ELSE condition inside the RUle function in Jquery Validation.

I am using one form for some fields are require for option 1 and some fields are require for option 2.

Example

for the below code I need name and address for option one and name and url for option 2. How to use the IF/Else condition for this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){      
        $("#demo-form").validate({    
          rules: {
            name: "required",
            address: "required",
            url: "required url",
            integer: {
        required:true,
        integer:true,
        min: 5
        },
       }
       });
```

Comment: Dumb Question: Why not do it by server side language?

Comment: Its the requirement the validation needs to be done in client side using jquery

Comment: i guess you didnt understood my question, ill show an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use inline if statement:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
        $("#demo-form").validate({    
          rules: {
            name: someCondition ? "required" : "notrequired",
            address: "required",
            url: "required url",
            integer: {
        required:true,
        integer:true,
        min: 5
        },
       }
       });
```

Where `someCondition` evaluates too boolean, ex: `($('selectedOption').val() == 1)`

Note: in the place of `notrequired` put whatever is the correct name for when property is not required.

Answer (score 0):

`sZipCode: page.langID == 1 ? {required: true, minlength: 5, number: true, range: [1, 79999]} : {required: true, minlength: 5, number: true, rangesk: [1000,9999,80000, 99999]},`

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable (needs 4 spaces at the line start, code tags are not working, afaik and you experienced :)

Answer (score 0):

```
depends: function(element) {
                if ($(("#selectid option:selected").val() == '3').is(':checked')){
                    code:"required";
                    creditLimit:"required";
                    depositAmont:"required";
                    idProofNumber:"required";
                    identyProof:"required";
                        "panNumber"{panNumber:true;}
                        return true;
                }else{return false;}
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is obviously old but I believe it is still relevant. The current Jquery Validate plugin includes syntax to allow for conditions to be met before making a field required. For example, if you want a field to be required only if a checkbox has been checked you will use:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: "#other:checked"
        }
    }
});
```

**Note**: Here the checkbox with ID of `other` must be checked for input with attribute `name='email'` to be required.

Alternatively, you could write a function in the rules object to check for another element's value before making a separate element required. For example:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        age: {
            required: true,
            min: 3
        },
        parent: {
            required: function(element) {
            return $("#age").val() < 13;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Note**: Here the value of the input field with attribute `name='age'` must have a value less than 13 for the input field with attribute `name='parent'` to be required. It is important you pass the element argument in this function.

Both these examples were taken for Jquery Validation Plugin's website, here is the link: https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/

Answer (score -1):

why not do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#demo-form").validate({
        rules: {
            <% if (option1=true) { %>
            name: "required",
            <% } %>
            address: "required",
            url: "required url",
            integer: {
                required: true,
                integer: true,
                min: 5
            },
        }
    });
```